# How to update a hidden field value from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JSP page where I Select `5` item rows. I am adding the Select  `Id`s in `sdata` array. I added a hidden button. `alert` is showing the full list. How can I set this list to the hidden field's(`mids`) value?

```
<input type="hidden" name="mids" value="">
```

JavaScript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var sdata =new Array();

  fn-create-ids{
     (checckbox.each.check())
      {
        sdata.push(i);
      }
      document.GetelementbyName("mids").value=sdata;
      alert(document.GetelementbyName("mids").value);---shows value
   }
 If I add it here, it is empty
 document.GetelementbyName("mids").value=sdata;---empty
}
```

Comment: UM, that is not valid JavaScript. There is no `GetelementbyName` I have no clue what that random `fn-....checckbox.....` lines are supposed to actually be.

Comment: `document.GetelementbyName` should be replaced with `document.getElementsByName`

Comment: Actually I'm wondering how it works because `document.getElementsByName` returns an array. You can't write something like `document.getElementsByName("mids").value`

Comment: @SinaSadrzadeh : thats why we use  document.getElementById

Comment: There's no non-plural version of the function, because it is *valid* to have multiple elements with the same name; it's like an API slap to developers assuming otherwise. IDs are generally what you're thinking of.

Comment: It sort of looks like jQuery mixed with syntax error ridden DOM access.

Comment: I believe that `document.getElementById` is the solution. but `alert(document.GetelementbyName("mids").value);---shows value` is a confusing point. Does it really shows the value?!

Comment: @SinaSadrzadeh : yh..i have answered that

Answer (score 0):

Give these hidden fields some ids

and then use

```
document.getElementById('hiddenfieldID').value +="your value";
```

in javascript

**Example**:

```
  document.getElementById('mid').value += sdata;
```

**BUT**

Really didn't understand how this function works

```
fn-create-ids{
     (checckbox.each.check())
      {
        sdata.push(i);
      }
   }
```

i think the value should be `i`

```
document.getElementById('mid').value +=i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sajad's answer is valid, but if you want to keep using just names, here's how. (You may already have a form in your document; if so, then just use the existing 'name' attribute for the Javascript)

```
<form name="midsForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="mids" value="">
</form>
```

Then:

```
document.forms.midsForm.mids.value = "your value";
```

Comment: or `document.getElementsByName("mids")[0].value=...`

Comment: @mplungjan And, then let's say your navigation developer adds a usually-hidden "navForm" above the page that happens to have a "mids" input. Still valid HTML, but suddenly, your form broke! Granted, "mids" is an uncommon identifier.

Comment: Or they call the navform midsForm then your code will fail too

Answer (score 0):

I have a header column which is a Checkbox(parent-check). Dynamically, I am filling bottom rows. Now when I select "parent-check", it is selecting all 13 rows that come from db. I have a submit button at the bottom outside of my display tag. when I click submit, I am going to another page. I will Select the check box(parent-check) to select all rows and then I will click submit. By this time, I want javascript to update my hidden field value with the array that will contain all selected row ids.
Jsp: 
In my existing script, I found this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var sdata =new Array();

  $("#parent-check").click(function() {
     if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $("td>:checkbox").each(function() {
            sdata.push($(this).attr("mids");
        });
      }
      document.GetelementbyName("mids").value=sdata;
      alert(document.GetelementbyName("mids").value);---shows value
   }
 If I add it here, it is empty
 document.GetelementbyName("mids").value=sdata;---empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is getting the array list inside a function. But the list becomes empty when I come out of the function though I declare it outside of the function under $( document ).ready(function().